# scaling different objects using mouse wheel

Tags: opengl, glfw, glm-math

I use `glfw` and `glm`.

If I scroll up - I want to make object bigger, when I scroll down - I want to make object smaller.

How to do it?
I use this function to handle mouse scrolling.

```
static void mousescroll(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
   if (yoffset > 0) { 
       scaler += yoffset * 0.01; //make it bigger than current size
       world = glm::scale(world, glm::vec3(scaler, scaler, scaler));
   }
   else {
       scaler -= yoffset * 0.01; //make it smaller than current size
       world = glm::scale(world, glm::vec3(scaler, scaler, scaler));
   }
}
```

By default `scaler` is `1.0`.

*I can describe the problem like this.*

There is an object. If I scroll up - the value of `scaler` will become `1.01`. So the object will be bigger in `1.01` times. When I scroll up again - as far as I can understand in my case the size of object will be bigger in `1.02` than the previous size(which is bigger than the original in `1.01` times)! But I want its size to be bigger than the original in `1.02` times.

How to solve this problem?

Matrix `world` looks like this

```
glm::mat4 world = glm::mat4(
glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

And I calculate the positions of vertex in the shader

`gl_Position = world * vec4(Position, 1.0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want its size to be bigger than the original in 1.02 times.

Then reset the transform each time instead of accumulating the scales:

```
world = glm::scale( scaler, scaler, scaler );
```